# Cant find Element

Tags: javascript, html

So I want to write out the text inside  input value item and make a another node to right of the text. But this text just shows [object HTMLParagraphElement] next to the text in the input, why doesnt it shows the text?

I dont know what I do wrong, please help me!

so the text from the input is showed but not the other p element I made?

Here is the code:

```
   var lista = document.getElementById("lista");

var li = document.createElement("li");

var del = document.createElement("p");
var delt = document.createTextNode("remove this");
del.appendChild(delt);


var item = document.getElementById("item");

var text = document.createTextNode(item.value + " | " + del);


li.appendChild(text);
lista.appendChild(li);
```

Comment: Please also show the html code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to use del.innerHTML.

```
var text = document.createTextNode(item.value + " | " + del.innerHTML);
```

the argument of document.createTextNode must be a string.And the innerHTML is the html code of a element object.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create text nodes to append the text. Just set the innerHTML on the elements you are creating:

```
var myPar = document.createElement('p');
myPar.innerHTML = "remove this";

li.innerHTML = myPar.outerHTML; //this would be the tag and its text <p>remove this</p>

// other code here.
```

Demo [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CqB6C/)

Answer (score 1):

the problem is the line

```
var text = document.createTextNode(item.value + " | " + del);
```

at this time ,the 'del' referenced a paragraph element,
you could have "del.innerHtml" instead of 'del'

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/4YgXG/

HTML:

```
<ul id="lista"></ul>
```

Js:

```
// EXAMPLE!
var lista = document.getElementById("lista");
var item = document.getElementById("item");

for(var i=0;i<100;i++){
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    var del = document.createElement("p");
    del.innerHTML = 'Remove this';
    li.appendChild( del );
    lista.appendChild(li);
}
```